# Kubuntu 20.04 missing network-manager-sstp

Tags: network-manager, 20.04

Just install new kubuntu 20.04... from gui it has sstp option.. but when i go to connect it says "Missing VPN Plugin"

No package to install?

```
$ sudo apt install network-manager-
network-manager-applet                      network-manager-iodine-gnome                network-manager-pptp-gnome
network-manager-config-connectivity-debian  network-manager-l2tp                        network-manager-ssh
network-manager-config-connectivity-ubuntu  network-manager-l2tp-gnome                  network-manager-ssh-gnome
network-manager-dev                         network-manager-openconnect                 network-manager-strongswan
network-manager-fortisslvpn                 network-manager-openconnect-gnome           network-manager-vpnc
network-manager-fortisslvpn-gnome           network-manager-openvpn                     network-manager-vpnc-gnome
network-manager-gnome                       network-manager-openvpn-gnome               
network-manager-iodine                      network-manager-pptp
```

Answer (score 4):

SSTP was never present in default package repository.

You must add following repository and than will be SSTP VPN available

https://launchpad.net/~eivnaes/+archive/ubuntu/network-manager-sstp

Long story short:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:eivnaes/network-manager-sstp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install network-manager-sstp sstp-client
```